# Как реализовать правило urlmanager?

Tags: yii2

вот структура модуль (serial) контроллер(category)экшен(oneserial). составил такое правило.

```
'serial/<id:/w+>'=>'serial/category/oneserial'
```

вот пытаюсь написать адрес ссылки

```
<?= Yii::$app->UrlManager->createUrl(['serial/category/oneserial','id'=>$car->name_serial]) ?>
```

получаю такой адрес

```
http://film.lc/serial/category/oneserial?id=Перевозчик+(сериал)
```

хочу получить

```
serial/Перевозчик+(сериал)
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в регулярке: не `/w+`, а `\w+` ...

Comment: @RomanGrinyov не помогло, но согласен :(

Comment: В общем, я попробовал сымитировать (естественно с правильной регуляркой) вашу ситуацию и у меня всё выходит как нужно: `serial/blablabla`. Так что что-то у вас с правилами для `urlManager`'а, мне так кажется ...

Comment: @RomanGrinyov а вы можете мне показать эту регулярку.

Comment: Я имею в виду как я говорил выше, в первом сообщении: не `/w+`, а `\w+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Yii::$app->UrlManager->createUrl('serial/' . $car->name_serial)
```

Comment: 404 вывалилась ошибка

Comment: изменил     Yii::$app->UrlManager->createUrl('serial/category/serial/' . $car->name_serial) на     Yii::$app->UrlManager->createUrl('serial/' . $car->name_serial), я написал концепцию как это сделать а работчю ссылку вы подставляете согласно того как у вас организован роутинг (попробуйте счас то что в ответе)